# ASP.Net timer control is needed

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET web application, in UI layer I have a C# class (not asp.net page) where I want to use timer control to send emails when timer elapse. I will start timer in application.start() method. I want to set it in background that will continue its working in background Please suggest either it is workable solution? If not then what can be alternate solution? I have read that timer control is not possible in web application as it is stateless environment but I want  to use it in C# class not in ASP.net page. Please suggest solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Test it first to know the timer is never collected by GC on your server:

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="mail.domain.com" password="psw" userName="user"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication {

    Timer cron;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cron = new Timer(1000 * 60 * 5);
        cron.AutoReset = true;
        cron.Start();
        cron.Elapsed += (s, a) => {
            var address = "your@email.com";
            var mail = new MailMessage("Test <test@domain.com>", address);
            mail.Subject = "Test";
            mail.Body = "Timer test at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Send(mail);
        };
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cron.Stop();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution as well as others ([thread loop](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive), [cache expiration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)) are hacky. Windows Task Scheduler is designed to do this kind of job.